# Porque o arquivo app.component.css não funciona no Angular?

Tags: css, angular

Quando executamos no Angular o comando `ng g c page --spec=false` ele cria um componente composto por quatro arquivos, um arquivo HTML, um arquivo de modulo,  um arquivo de CSS e um arquivo **TS** como mostra na figurar abaixo, no meu caso abaixo não precisei executar o comando porque veio nativamente do Framworks;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O arquivo CSS não funciona apesar de estarei interligados como mostra no código abaixo;

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

Essa são as configurações que coloquei no meu arquivo css que está com o nome de **app.component.css**

```
body{
    background: #098778;
}
```

Por favor, esse arquivo CSS está no projeto só de enfeite ou é porque estou fazendo algo errado?

Se estou fazendo algo errado o que devo fazer para ele funcionar?

Eu já sei que existe um arquivo padrão na raiz do projeto com o **style.css**, ele serve de configuração global do projeto, o que eu preciso é que o arquivo **app.component.css** funcione!

Comment: Nao existe a tag body dentro desse seu componente.

Comment: É isso mesmo, pode colocar sua resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O app css e especifico do app component, o body esta acima dele no dom logo nao ira funcionar. Para mudar o estilo global você tem que mudar o arquivo style.css

o que vc pode tentar no app.css e algo assim:

```
:host{
    width:100vw;
    hight:100vh;
    background: blue;
}
```